# Contenteditable div with selectAll on focus not working entirely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some divs in a table like this one:

```
<div contenteditable="true"
     onfocus="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Something</div>
```

When focusing a div by clicking it, it all works fine, the whole text is being selected.

The problem is that I want the same behaviour when navigating between divs by tab. As it is, navigating by tab just lets me edit the div without selecting the text.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Show some more code. What ever you tried or coded so far.

Comment: You should delay it: `setTimeout(function(){document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)},0)`

Comment: Great, this worked. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it. If you could explain it as well it would be great.

Comment: @Dragos For explaination, see the `use a timeout` link in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute command after element is focused, not on focus. To delay it, you can [use a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful), this will put callback in event queue, executing it after element is focused.

Your code should be (without using any inline script but jQuery as tagged in question):

```js
$('div[contenteditable]').on('focus', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null)
  }, 0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable>Something</div>
<div contenteditable>Something New</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below function to select all the content of a content editable div.

```js
 const onSelectText = (event) => {
    if (window.getSelection) {
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      const range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(event.currentTarget);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
  };
```

```css
.select-text{
width:200px;
border:1px solid black;
padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-text" contentEditable="true" onClick=onSelectText(event)>Hello, welcome to my world</div>
```

content editable div.